# Do I get to fetch a basic land when putting my commander in the command zone for Path to Exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Someone told me this a couple of day ago, and I want a second ruling. I was told if your commander gets [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d)'d and you choose to put it in the command zone, you don't to search your deck for the basic land, just like with [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d) you don't gain life, due to the way the card is written.

Comment: Actually, you do get life from Swords to Plowshares.

Answer (score 10):

This concerns the following rule:

> CR 903.9. If a commander would be exiled from anywhere or put into its owner’s hand, graveyard, or library from anywhere, its owner may put it into the command zone instead. This replacement effect may apply more than once to the same event. This is an exception to rule 614.5.

If the Commander's owner chooses to apply the replacement effect, you perform the following instructions when resolving [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d):

> <del>Exile target creature.</del>*Move target creature to the command zone.* Its controller may search his or her library for a basic land card, put that card onto the battlefield tapped, then shuffle his or her library.

There's nothing preventing the rest of the ability from resolving, so you do get to search your library for a land.

Similarly, you perform the following instructions when resolving [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d):

> <del>Exile target creature.</del>*Move target creature to the command zone.* Its controller gains life equal to its power.

So, you do gain life.

---

Let's consider a different scenario. Say there's a creature on the battlefield with the following ability:

> Whenever a creature dies, ...

Then, let's say you cast the following spell targeting a Commander:

> Destroy target creature. Draw a card.

- If the Commander's owner doesn't replace the effect,

  You perform the following instructions when resolving the spell:

  > Destroy target creature (*by moving it to the graveyard*). Draw a card.

  The triggered ability will obviously trigger.
- If the Commander's owner chooses to apply the replacement effect,

  You perform the following instructions when resolving the spell:

  > Destroy target creature (*by moving it to the <del>graveyard</del>*command zone). Draw a card.

  Since the creature never died (never went to the graveyard from the battelfield), the triggered ability won't trigger.

Either way, you draw a card.

Comment: This implies control over where the commander goes by the player exiling it, which is wrong and misleading. The cards still do very much the same, but the player owning the commander may choose to put it in the command zone instead of into exile, as explained in the other answers.

Comment: @TheThirdMan, Fixed

Comment: It's still misleading, and always will be with this approach - the commander's controller won't have to choose until the respective spell resolves, and they get to choose *because* the spell exiles a creature. Over-simplifying this by suggesting that cards do different things depending on which creatures are targetted is wrong and isn't helping anyone, especially in situations as uncomplex as this one. By abstraction, you're promoting that learning how replacement effects work is unnecessary.

Comment: Re "*It's still misleading*", There's nothing misleading; this is exactly what happens. /// Re "*and always will be with this approach*", There is no other approach. This is the "approach" defined in the rules. /// Re "*the commander's controller won't have to choose until the respective spell resolves*", I never said or implied otherwise.

Comment: Re "*Over-simplifying this by suggesting that cards do different things depending on which creatures are targetted*", That's not an over-simplification. That's actually what happens. The spell's text doesn't change, but the spell's effect does as described. /// Re "*you're promoting that learning how replacement effects work is unnecessary*", To the contrary, I'm explaining how they work.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the rule, which replaces the event of a commander being put into exile - it doesn't replace a spell trying to put a commander into exile. The spell always says "Exile target creature", and at the time that happens and the creature would be put into exile, the replacement effect kicks in and - if the creature is a commander - allows it's controller to put it in the command zone instead. You're describing the non-existant rule saying "If a spell would say to exile a commander creature, and it's controller chooses to put it in the command zone, it says sth. else instead"

Comment: Re "*it doesn't replace a spell trying to put a commander into exile*", I know. It doesn't replace the spell at all. It just replaces one of the spell's instructions. That's the entire point of my answer. /// Re "*You're describing the non-existant rule saying*", Not true at all. I didn't say it says something else instead -- in fact, I've specifically said the spell's text doesn't change -- I said it DOES something else instead. I've updated the answer to use clearer wording.

Comment: Again, it does **not** replace one of the spell's instructions. It changes what happens when the spell's (unchanged) instructions are executed. You could visualize it the way you described to simplify it, but what's actually happening doesn't touch the spell at all. What you're talking about is not a replacement effect, but something like [Alter Reality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=34832), and nothing about the rule says anything remotely close. If I had to take a guess, I'd say you've been mislead by the very same logic yourself.

Comment: Re "*Again, it does not replace one of the spell's instructions*", This is the first time you've said this, and it's wrong. It DOES change the spell's instructions. The Commander doesn't get exiled and then go to the command zone. You move it directly to the command zone. This also matters when things query the source of the effect. (e.g. Protection, etc). They see the spell, not the source of the replacement effect.

Comment: Alter Reality alters text, so I'm clearly NOT talking about Alter Reality. (Alter Reality is not a replacement effect; it's a continuous effect that alters the attributes of an object (much like Giant Growth).)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may get a land (if you want to and can search your library).

Putting your commander in the command zone instead of the zone it would normally go to becomes relevant if an effect would trigger whenever the/a creature changes zones. This could be "whenever a creature dies" as in the example below or if a card refers to an exiled card ([mimic vat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bmimic%20vat%5d)). Your commander never died and is not exiled with the vat, if you chose to move it to the command zone.

An example would be, if you commander dies when equipped with [skullclamp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bskullclamp%5d). If you want to draw two cards, you have to let it go into your graveyard - if you return it to the command zone, it doesn't die and you don't draw.

Since dieing is the most common scenario in which this replacement effect happens, you might also want to look at : [Do commanders “die” if they go to the command zone instead?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/do-commanders-die-if-they-go-to-the-command-zone-instead)

thanks @doppelgreener, dieing is not the only situation in which it matters

Comment: "whenever a creature dies" wouldn't be relevant for a card that exiles though.

Comment: This is correct. However, since the most common situation where the replacement effect matters is it dying I though it would be helpful to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official rules](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php):

> If a Commander would be put into a library, hand, graveyard or exile from anywhere, its owner may choose to move it to the command zone instead.

This means that casting [Path to Exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPath%20to%20Exile%5d) or [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d) on a commander will - on resolution - allow it's controller to choose whether to put it in the command zone, or exile it (probably a bad idea). The spell, however, won't be affected by that choice, and the commander's controller will get to search their library for a basic land or gain life.

You're probably thinking of spells getting countered by the game rules for not having any legal targets, but that's not what's happening here. The Commander rules create a replacement effect, so Path to Exile fully resolves, just it's effect might be altered.

Comment: The spell is affected because it's the spell that places the Commander in the command zone. That's how replacement effects work. The key is that only the "move" part of the spell is replaced, while the rest is performed normally (as shown in my answer).

Comment: @ikegami: This might be a misunderstanding - yes, the replacement effect alters the way each spell will work *effectively* (though very much unlike you suggested in your answer, as I added in the comments), but the spell won't be affected by the choice the commander's controller takes.

Comment: No, the replacement effect alters the way the spells work *period*. As its name suggests, it literally replaces part of the spell's effect by replacing one instruction with another.